# for loop through sql data in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a MySQL database with the columns: id, username, userid, amount, status. I'm currently getting it this way

```
$data = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT * 
      FROM creditlogs 
     WHERE userid = :uid 
       AND status = credit
    ")
$data->bindValue(':uid', $urld['id'])
$data->execute()
$userData = $data->fetch()
```

Whats the proper for statement/method to get it to do it like in javascript where you can do

```js
for (const i in data){
console.log(i[1])
}
```

Comment: First you'll need to edit your query so that it orders the results by the date/time column, and use the LIMIT clause to get only ten rows. Once you've done that, surround your `fetch()` in a `while()` loop and display the results. And fix the typo in the bindValue of course.

Comment: Whats the best way to order it by date column, because I haven't added one yet. The typo was someone else editing it but I'll fix it rn.

Comment: Add one, then order it by that column. If you want the "most recent" you need some way of deciding which those are. You could use the auto-incrementing id probably.

Comment: Yes, the ID is auto_increment

Comment: That would probably do it then. I can't think of a reason it wouldn't, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: Don't use the id - it's not its purpose! An record of an older date could be inserted later, it would have a higher id, but refer to an earlier date...

Comment: Ok, but anyone know how to make it echo it?

Comment: I don't plan to be manually inserting anything into that table, its completely automated so that should be fine.